# Epics in Jira whose Epic-Story Link is from specific project

Tags: jira, jql

I would like to find all epics that have "Issues in Epic" from a specific Project.
Current JQL:

```
project = FOO AND issuetype = Epic AND key in (FOO-1, FOO-2, FOO-3)
```

I can add `and issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("project = BAR and issueFunction in hasLinkType('Epic-Story Link')")`, but it gives me epics which have other types of linked issues (eg. clones, related ..)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the described behavior.

These are all link types: `Blocks, Cloners, Duplicate, Epic-Story Link, Gantt End to End, Gantt End to Start, Gantt Start to End, Gantt Start to Start, Parent-Child Link, Problem/Incident, Relates, Solves`

It seems that `Epic-Story Link` is handled like a super type of some of the other ones during query evulation. That's just a suggestion and I dunno why this should be.

However, the following query should work for your purpose

`project = FOO AND issuetype = Epic AND issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("project = BAR AND 'Epic Link' is not EMPTY")`

Comment: It's a bit closer to the solution. But a couple of issues. 1. it's `'Epic Link'` and not `'Epic-Link`' 2. this still gives all other types of links. In my case, it outputs a single epic of the correct project and type. But this issue has multiple types of links (parent task, related, tested by), and the 'Issues in Epic' links. However, the latter only has issue from project BAZ and none from project BAR

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a scrum board, import all issues you want to sort on and see which ones are empty opening the epics panel?